# For what values of $x$ in $(-3,17)$ does the series $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n[\log (n+1)]^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

For what values of $x$ in the following series, does the series converge?

\begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(-1)^n x^n}{n[\log (n+1)]^2},\;\;-3<x<17 \end{align}

**MY TRIAL**

\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{n+1}}{(n+1)[\log (n+2)]^2}\cdot\dfrac{n[\log (n+1)]^2}{(-1)^n x^n}\right|&=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot\left[\dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log (n+2)}\right]^2\right|\\&=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)\cdot\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[\dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log (n+2)}\right]^2\\&=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)\cdot\left[\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log (n+2)}\right]^2\\&=|x|\left[\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n+1}\cdot n+2\right]^2\\&=|x|\end{align}
Hence, the series converges absolutely for $|x|<1$ and diverges when $|x|>1$.

When $x=1,$
\begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(-1)^n }{n[\log (n+1)]^2}<\infty\;\;\text{By Alternating series test}\end{align}
When $x=-1,$
\begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n[\log (n+1)]^2}<\infty\;\;\text{By Direct comparison test}\end{align}
Hence, the values of $x$ for which the series converges, is $-1\leq x\leq 1.$

I'm I right? Constructive criticisms will be highly welcome! Thanks!

Comment: For me it's right

Comment: Fine for me too. I just wouldn't speak of alternating series test, because the series is in fact absolutely convergent. Why use a precision tool when you can use a hammer ? :-)

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS: Smiles...

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS:You mean the series \begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(-1)^n }{n[\log (n+1)]^2}\end{align} converges absolutely for $x=1?$ How?

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS:: Oh, I see! Robert Z has cleared my confusion! Thanks!

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles, please.

Comment: @Did: Yes Sir! I agree!

Comment: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(-1)^n }{n[\log (n+1)]^2}<\infty$$ I'd recommend just saying "converges by the alternating series test" Using $<\infty$ here doesn't mean much.

Comment: @zhw: Ok, I got you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. This is a "variation on the theme".

For $|x|>1$
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{|-x|^n}{n[\log (n+1)]^2}=+\infty$$
and the series is divergent.

For $|x|\leq 1$, by direct comparison, the series is absolutely convergent
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{|-x|^n}{n[\log (n+1)]^2}\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n[\log (n+1)]^2}<\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, for the limit from here we can proceed as follow

$$\ldots=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot\left[\dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log (n+2)}\right]^2\right|
=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{1+1/n}\cdot\left[\dfrac{\log n+\log (1+1/n)}{\log n+\log (1+2/n)}\right]^2=|x|\cdot1=|x|$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate!